# Column-level locking in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server I have a table with 10 columns, I want to update a particular column value in the table, & I want to put lock before updating by which others cannot update the table at same time. ex- i have two column names are id1 & id2, at any time only one column will be updated, so i want to put a lock only on that column, reamin column should be free for other user can update it.

Comment: Are you talking about having the lock apply during a single `UPDATE` statement, or are you talking of some kind of "application level" feature, where the user is inspecting and editing values within the column over a period of minutes/hours?

Comment: SQL Server's `UPDATE` statement will **automatically** cause a row-level UPDATE lock ..... so what more do you need???

Comment: -1, vote to close. Not a real question. To the poster: At least have one sentence that can semantically correct end with a "?". To be a question, ou have to ASK one. "I want" is not a question. At least not in the rest of the world.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest level lock in SQL Server is a row lock; you can't lock per column.

For `update`, SQL Server takes care of [locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) by itself.  Before it runs the update, it will acquire a lock.  This can be a row, page or table lock.  It will then do the update and release the lock after the update is committed.